# if statement not working in shell script

Tags: shell, if-statement

Below is my script and the `val1` value is *3* and `val2` value is *0* , but by default the condition checks the `if` statement.  Not going to `else` condition. Can anyone help show where I missed or did something wrong here?

```
op1=$(top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | awk '{print$2}' | sed -e 's/%us,//g')
op2=$(top -bn1 | grep "load average" | awk '{print$12}' |sed -e 's/,//g')
val2=${op2%.*}
val1=${op1%.*}
echo $val1
echo $val2

if [ val1 > 50 ] || [ val2 > 50 ] ; then

  echo -e "CPU Percentage on $HOSTNAME is  $op1  and Current  Load is  $op2  Which are higher than 50% usage. Kindly Login to $HOSTNAME and examine  the process. If apache process consume the more space kindly execute the following command to restart all the SWLB's. \n\n Host Name    : $HOSTNAME   \n User ID          : inauat \n Path              :/inautilus/xjp/ers/servers \n Script Name : apache_all.sh  \n\n Note: If the SWLB restart doesn't resolve the problem, contact Unix support  to investigate further. "| mutt -s " $HOSTNAME CPU Status Alert  " "test@testdomain.com" -c "test@testdomain@inautix.co.in"

else
    echo  'CPU load appears normal.'
fi
```

Comment: $val1 instead of just val1 inside the if?

Comment: The first `echo` is a mile long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `if` statement as below:

```
if [ "$val1" -gt 50 ] || [ "$val2" -gt 50 ] ; then
#your code here
fi
```